# is the cairo context life-time limited?

Tags: x11, cairo

Unfortunately I have to ask because the documentation doesn't specify this very well.

Is the `cairo_t` and the `cairo_surface_t` life-time limited ?

In many examples or samples found over the web, the surface and the context are almost always recreated (more oftently the context) for each repaint operation.

Actually it seems to work almost finely if I only create the surface and the context once, lazily, like here, when a x11 windows is resized:

```c
void updateWindowSize()
{
    if(!display || !_win)
        return;

    int w = cast(uint) lround(width);
    int h = cast(uint) lround(height);

    if (!_osSetSizePos)
        XResizeWindow(display, _win, w, h);
    if (!cairoSurface)
        cairoSurface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(display, _win, _visual, w, h);
    cairo_xlib_surface_set_size(cairoSurface, w, h);

    if (!_cr) _cr = cairo_create(cairoSurface);
    _cv.setContext(_cr); // _cv = canvas
}
```

However the context has to be passed each time to the canvas `_cv.setContext(_cr);` otherwise the settings are never applied (color, pen width,...), which is crazy since the context itself never changes.

This completely goes against what I've seen before., including the answers to [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519723/3661500).

The underlying problem is that if the context is recreated for each redrawing then the operations such as `cairo_set_source_rgba`, `cairo_set_source`, `cairo_set_line_width`, etc., have to be done for each redrawing too, which can be seen as a performance issue.

Comment: You are saying that operations such as `cairo_set_source_rgba()` etc are a performance issue. Why do you think so? Are you just making this up or is this really a performance issue? Why? How do you know/measure?

Comment: Actually my remark about the perf was not pertinent, since during a single drawing operation, each time someting has to be filled with its own pattern, the pattern has to be redefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the lifetimes aren't limited (at least by cairo). You can use both for as long as you want. You don't even need to recreate the surface for window resizes, because there is `cairo_xlib_surface_set_size()`. (There even is `cairo_xlib_surface_set_drawable()` which can change the drawable, but personally I don't like that function.)

However, libraries like GTK might add some requirements. For example, GTK does double buffering and there contexts can't be cached.

Comment: The surface clearly not. But I encounter a problem in the canvas If I don't recreate the context.

Comment: ...which? Do you have any complete, self-contained sample code that I could try out?

Comment: No, but now the problems i mentioned are fixed, they were caused by an erroneous usage of cairo_save and cairo_restore. Now it's crystal clear: single context works fine during the whole application life-time (at least without double buffering).